# Label specific points in a plot

Tags: r, plot, label

Here I have two vectors: "Pr" and "Z"

here is my code:

```
Z=seq(1,10,by=0.5)
Pr=lapply(Z,functionZ)

plot(Z,Pr,main="CAT Bond Price with increasing attachment points",xlab="Attachment Point",ylab="Price")
 grid(nx = NULL, ny = NULL, col = "blue", lty = "dotted")
```

I want to select **only** two points in the plot, namely those where Z=5, and Z=7.5 and label them as "Class A" and "Class B" respectively. How can I do that?

Comment: can you put i what functionz is so we can reproduce this? Also I know ggplot has a way to label only specific things, and it looks really nice too

Comment: Or just skip the function entirely and make up some simple number: x 1-5, y: 1-5, label 2 and 4...

Answer (score 2):

To stick with your base R plotting,  you can use the `text` function.

Since you do not provide your `FunctionZ` I just use some example.  I placed the labels to the left of the points.  Depending on the shape of your function,  you may wish to adjust the `pos` argument to place them elsewhere.

```
Z=seq(1,10,by=0.5)
functionZ = function(x) x + sin(x)
Pr=lapply(Z,functionZ)

plot(Z,Pr,main="CAT Bond Price with increasing attachment points",
    xlab="Attachment Point",ylab="Price")
grid(nx = NULL, ny = NULL, col = "blue", lty = "dotted")

text(x=c(5,7.5), y=functionZ(c(5,7.5)), labels= c("Class A", "Class B"), pos=2)
```

[image: Labeled Plot]

Answer (score 0):

Your example is not reproducible, so I made up some random data and plotted with ggplot:

```
  Z=seq(1,10,by=0.5)
  Pr <- 1:19
  L <- c("Point1", rep(NA, 17), "Point19")
  df <- data.frame(Pr, Z, L)

  library(ggplot2)
  ggplot(aes(x=Pr, y=Z, label=L), data=df) +
    geom_point() +
    geom_label() +
    xlab("Attachment Point") +
    ylab("Price") +
    ggtitle("CAT Bond Price with increasing attachment points") +
    theme_classic()
```

You just define which ones you want to show labels for in a separate labels column and ggplot does the rest.

In your case, when you define L just do

```
 L <- ifelse(Z==7, "Class A", ifelse(Z==7.5, "Class B", NA))
```

Comment: `geom_text` is another label adding option. Between the two there is a lot of extra options like moving the position of the label or customising the appearance of the label to suit your data